# Count mixed fields in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables with next columns:

Table`products`contains

1. product_id [numeric]
2. provider [numeric]

Table `orders` contains

1. order_id [numeric]
2. cart_items (consists of multiple product_id's) for instance:
   [{"product_id":304,"amount":250,"currency_rate":"1.28"},{"product_id":306,"amount":10,"currency_rate":"1.05"}]

Question: how can I query in Google Big Query to count sold product_id's (mentioned in cart_items) from a certain provider grouped by product_id?

Comment: What is the data type of `cart_items`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an array of structs.  So, use `unnest()`:

```
select item.product_id, count(*)
from orders o cross join
     unnest(cart_items) item
group by 1;
```